# If $f$ is a periodic function, prove $g(x) = f(ax+b)$ is a periodic function

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Given $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ a periodic function, $g(x) = f(ax+b)$ and $a, b$ are real numbers with $a \ne 0$, I want to prove that $g$ is a periodic function.

The first logical step in my opinion would be:

Suppose $\exists\ T \ne0$ and $g(x) = g(x+T), \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}$. We would have $f(ax+b)= f(a(x+T)+b)$ $\forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}$. I would start giving $x$ values such as $0$: $f(b) = f(aT + b)$. If $x$ is $1$: $f(a+b) = f(a + aT + b)$. We see that $aT$ is repeating itself. How should I continue from here?

When I was writing this post, a suggested post (which I will link) [had appeared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661006/fx-is-a-periodic-function-with-period-t). It's indeed really similar but the conclusions differ a bit and I don't know how should I connect the "pieces" to solve the problem so to speak. Any hints or methods of continuing?

Comment: You can do this by direct computation. The form of the argument of $f$ is just shifting the point $x \to ax+b$ and because $f$ is periodic with period $T$, you have $$\dots = f(ax+b) = f(a(x+T)+b) = \dots$$

Comment: Thank you for your input! I think I finally understood the solution :)